# Error while submitting aws emr job from command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, emr

I am getting below error form `aws emr`. I have submitted job from `cli`. The job status is pending.

> A client error (ThrottlingException) occurred when calling the ListSteps operation: Rate exceeded

How to see the all the active jobs in `emr` cluster and how to kill them from `cli` and also from the `aws` console.

Regards
sanjeeb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS APIs are rate limited. According to the AWS docs the recommended approach to dealing with a throttling response is to implement exponential backoff in your retry logic means when you get ThrottlingException try to catch it and sleep for some time say half second and then retry ...

Comment: See , one of my jobs has been execution for long time though it s 2 minutes job.It may be because of that. Can you tell me how to kill a emr job as I can see job execution from the aws console?

Comment: You can kill the job from AWS console by hitting terminate button or if your using AWS cli then use respective API